# Isn't possible to train the 'custom translator' programmatically?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I am new to custom translator for microsoft translator API. I can train it through the web ui. I am wondering that is it possible to create a program to submit training data to train the model? If so, could you please suggest me about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we have a restful api implemented for the Custom Translator.  Anything that can be done through the portal can be done through the api and more.  The swagger documentation is here

https://custom-api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/swagger/

Some sample code that explains and demonstrates the authentication process as well as few basic actions can be found here

https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/CustomTranslatorApiSamples

Comment: I followed the instruction and already get access_token. However, when I try to get category or workspace (which require only access_token), it always return 401. Noted that, I try using the form in swagger.

Comment: As Scott answered we can consume the API for submitting and training the data.